# color output for Windows batch file, in vscode snippet

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-code, colors, command-line-interface, vscode-snippets

I want to create a vscode snippet to make it easy to output colored text from a Windows .bat file.
Here's an example:

```
 "echo [1m[32mThis text in Green bold",
```

The escape character is there, but not visible in the SO output. It has a hex code of 1B (decimal: 27) and looks like a square. There's one in front of each [ character.
The error message from vscode is "invalid characters in string. Control characters should be escaped".

Putting backslash(es) in front of them doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSON files you can use the Unicode prefix `\uhhhh`.

```
  "Text Green Bold": {
    "prefix": "tgrb",
    "body": [
      "echo \u001b[1m\u001b[32mThis text in Green bold",
      "$0"
    ],
    "description": "Text in Green Bold"
  }
```